# Ruby code to remove from Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am wanting to write some ruby to iterate through documents in a collection in a MongoDB.

My data has the schema:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("560ff830eeb4db07875b59b9"), 
"userId" : NumberInt(1), 
"movieId" : NumberInt(50), 
"rating" : 4.0, 
"timestamp" : NumberInt(1329753504)
```

I firstly want to count each time userId = 1 is present in the whole collection, and if less than 5 discard them all.

I'm really unsure how to tackle this, so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to count the number of documents which have `userId = 1` through the **[`count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)** method. Thus from the shell (command-line), you can do the following:

```
var count = db.collection.find({ "userId": 1 }).count();
if (count < 5) db.collection.remove()
```

You'll then have to do something similar with Ruby, but it should be pretty straightforward. Refer to the documentation on the Ruby driver for this:

1. **[Get a count of matching documents in the collection.](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#count-instance_method)**
2. **[Remove documents from the collection](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#delete_many-instance_method)**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should be able to convert this into a ruby block.